# Automatic layout when widget space is finite in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to achieve the following effect using a Tkinter python app:

The user can define a finite number of list elements, aka categories.

I then would like to present these categories next to each other, based on the following approach:

```
l=Label(self.body,text='Category: ')
l.pack(side=Left)
for i in range(0,len(self.categories)):
   l=Label(self.body,text=self.category[i])
   l.pack(side=LEFT)
self.body.pack(fill=BOTH)
```

Of course, this does not work. Is there an elegant way to "wrap" a whole label at the widget borders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the size of the frame you are using to pack the labels into, and the width of the label.  You can set the width parameter for the label, but it uses a size that depends on the font used i.e. the same "width=" results in different label widths for different font sizes.  So it can not be done with the code you posted.  Link to label parameters http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm